# Is there a way for different directive calls on the same component to communicate between them?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I created a small validation framework so i can validate input by only referencing what i'm trying to validate, an example of it would be:

```
<input type="text" EV [EVTarget]="imthetarget" [EVType]="'EVEmail'">
<span #imthetarget></span>
<button EV [EVSubmit]="">SUBMIT</button>
```

Now, once the client clicks the submit button i would like it to find all EV inputs and corresponding directives and check if they have any errors on them.

My bad solution: I could create a hidden input and just place all the errors there and just check that field before allowing the data submission but that does not feel correct and would be clumsy.

Is there a way for the same directive instantiated multiple times within the same component to communicate with each other ?

This mini-project repo: https://github.com/maritto/Easy-Validate

Comment: Why not just use FormBuilder or Reactive Form? :) They have the ability to validate inputs without any hidden inputs.

Comment: Because this way i can create validation rules for the entire application by just adding one attribute to the desired field.
For example if i have multiple pages where i need the user to insert stack overflow links, i can create the validation rules under EVSOUrl and just apply them to the html input.

Comment: Hmm, I suspect you'll need to validate the entire form on main component anyways. But you can (probably) add custom validator on directive and return non-null value to indicate a validation error. But I'm not sure if this is sufficient approach for you.

Comment: That is exactly what i'm trying to avoid, i just want the main component to post the data and a global directive to do the validation on each component; remove repeated code.
I think im just gonna set a global variable with all the errors that gets cleared on the onnginit of the submit button.
That bad side of this is that i can only have one 'form' on each component.

Comment: Another approach is to create directive on a form itself. And emit “submit” on successful validation. But I’m not sure myself how to implement this as I haven’t tried before. Just throwing some ideas out there.

Comment: I ended up storing everything on static variables. If i couldn't make myself clear enough and left you curious about what i wanted just check the git and on the top, 
    static EVErrorsList: EVError[] = [];
    static EVElements: HTMLInputElement[] = [];
the functionality of those 2 variable were the issue i wanted to solve.
I still can only have one "button"/"form" per component though! x(

Comment: Eh, sorry I couldn't help much :|